# linked list node class data structure in java

Tags: java

```
 Public class Node
 {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data,Node p)
    {
       this.data=data;
       this.next=p;
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of Node next; in the above implementation

Comment: The next node in the list?

Comment: simple what is the self referential classes

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a list where every node in the list has both a data value, plus a link to the next node in the list.

In the above code, each node in the list is represented by a `Node` object.  Each `Node` object has a data value (`data`) and the next node in the linked list (`next`).

Also worth noting is that what you see here is known as a singly-linked list.  You can only navigate the list in one direction.  There are also doubly-linked lists, where each node has a `next` and a `previous`.  That allows you to navigate the list in either direction.

Comment: does it link to the next object that i create using node class? does "next " contain the pointer address of the next object of the same class?

Comment: It doesn't do anything automatically.  You'd have to create a new `Node` object, and assign it to the `next` member in your previous `Node` object yourself, using something like `node.next = new Node().`  And this raises an interesting issue that I just noticed.  You need a constructor that takes an int, but *doesn't* take a new node (and just sets `next` to null).  Otherwise, you'll never be able to add the last node in the list.

Comment: what is the meaning of "node head=null "mean linked list.

Comment: One of the items in your linked list has to be the last item.  That item can't have any value in its `next` variable, because there *is* no next;  it's the last one.  So for the last item, its `next` will be `null`.

Comment: Node curNode=head;then curNode.next!=null and curNode!=null mean same thing?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Node next; refers the next node on the List
2. This is not a linked list you should have Node previous; as well